# Como fazer para ignorar uma linha vazia em uma tabela

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma tabela e quando um valor for vazio eu gostaria que ignorasse o valor e fosse preenchido com a próxima linha com valor.

Com o código abaixo, nada aparece, nem com valor e nem sem valor.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="tblGrid">
<thead>
<tr>
<th align="left">Observações</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php while ($row_itens_vazio = $resultado_itens_vazio->fetch_array()) {?>
      <tr>
      <?php if($row_itens_vazio["obs_tab_itens_cot"]>0){?>
        <td align="left" class="td1">
           <?php echo $row_itens_vazio["obs_tab_itens_cot"];?>
        </td>
           <?php } ?> 
      </tr>
    <?php } ?> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A variável `$resultado_itens_vazio` está recebendo quais dados?

Comment: Posta a ```query``` pra gente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso usando o `continue` e o `empty` do php.

> Exemplo

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="tblGrid">
<thead>
<tr>
<th align="left">Observações</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php while ($row_itens_vazio = $resultado_itens_vazio->fetch_array()) {
             //verifica se um valor é vazio.
             if(empty($row_itens_vazio['obs_tab_itens_cot'])) {
                 continue; //volta para cima no próximo registro
             }
      ?>
      <tr>
      <?php if($row_itens_vazio["obs_tab_itens_cot"]>0){?>
        <td align="left" class="td1">
           <?php echo $row_itens_vazio["obs_tab_itens_cot"];?>
        </td>
           <?php } ?> 
      </tr>
    <?php } ?> 
</tbody>
</table>
```